# Possible to set transparency to XML gradient file?

Tags: android

Is it possible to set transparency in gradient which is set in the XML file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you have a gradient with 2 colors:

- `StartColor` **#111111**
- `EndColor` **#333333**

Adding transparency is as simple as adding 2 HEX digits to the beginning of each color

SO:

If you want the `StartColor` (for example) to be 100% opaque:

- change its value to **#FF111111**

If you want the `EndColor` (for example) to be 100% transparent:

- change its value to **#00333333**

You can of course use values between **00** and **FF** for transparency if you don't want the extreme values.

The values between HEX 00 and FF are values between 0 and 255 in normal numbers:

To transform from [0,255] to [00,FF]:

1. Open calculator in windows and change mode to scientific
2. There are options like : **Dec**, **Hex**, **Oct** ...

   Choose **Dec** and type the number between 0 and 255
3. Choose **Hex** and the number will become in hex between 00 and FF

Comment: Where can I find the values between 00 and FF? Let's say I want 55% transparency.

Comment: I think I found the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names which lead me to conclusio. HEX has 16 values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) where 8 is 50%, etc. This way I can set transparency up t0 6.25% precision (100 / 16). Is there a more precise way? Maybe some online tool?

Comment: open calculator in windows: `View` -> `Scientific`
Now enter a number between 0 and 255 (0 is **00** and 255 is **FF**)
Choose Hex and you will get the value

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `#AARRGGBB` format for the start/end colors, with the `AA` portion specifying the alpha channel (i.e., transparency).